# Setting GNU Screen to send escape codes to outer terminal on TI

Tags: terminal, cygwin, gnu-screen, less, mintty

I’m using GNU Screen inside mintty. To get the scroll wheel to work, I had to switch the mintty scroll wheel mode with an escape code (`^[[?7787h`). This has the effect that the scroll wheel does not work in `less` anymore. To fix this, I would need `less` to send the appropriate escape codes to the outer terminal on start and exit.

I found the `^[P` escape code that can be used to send escape codes to the terminal running Screen. So I wanted to add `^[P^[[?7787l` to the `ti` termcap inside screen. To achieve this  I added this line to my `.screenrc`:

```
termcapinfo * "" "\EP\E[?7787l\E[?1049h"
```

But that did not affect `less` at all. I know that `^[P^[[?7787l` works – if I just echo it, everything is fine. I could just write a `less` wrapper that handles that, but I would prefer to be able to do this via termcap, as it would then work in all aplications, not just in less.

So my question is: How can I change which escape codes `less` sends to the terminal when it switches to the alternative screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command should work:

```
termcapinfo * "" "ti=\EP\E[?7787l\E\\\E[?1049h:te=\EP\E[?7787h\E\\\E[?1049l"
```

(Replacing `*` with a more specific name for your terminal type would be even better, but I don't know what `TERM` value is set by mintty.)

Important differences from your version:

1. The second and third parameters of the `termcapinfo` command must contain termcap defines (`name=value`) separated by `:`, not just a bare escape sequence.
2. The `^[P` escape sequence must be terminated by `^[\`, otherwise too much further output goes to the terminal directly without proper processing by Screen (there is some safeguard to avoid locking up Screen completely if the termination sequence is forgotten, but the display will still be messed up).
3. You should change both `ti` and `te`, so that exiting from `less` (or any other fullscreen program) restores the previous state properly.

Of course, if you invoke `less` with the `-X` option, the mouse wheel will not work properly, because with this option `less` does not send the `ti` and `te` strings to the terminal. Remember that this option might be specified not directly in the `less` command line, but also through the `LESS` environment variable.

---

However, if `less` is compiled to use `terminfo` instead of `termcap`, the third parameter of the `termcapinfo` command will not change the behavior of `less`, because it influences only the contents of the `TERMCAP` environment variable exported by `screen` to its subprocesses, and the `terminfo` database contents cannot be changed dynamically. In this case you will need to use utilities like `infocmp` and `tic` to create a terminfo source entry which contains `smcup` and `rmcup` values with your modifications, and then compile the entry to the binary format; then use `term <your-entry-name>` in `.screenrc` to use this entry.

Comment: Thx a lot. I had (1) and (3) right, just messed that up in my question. (2) was my problem. It also turns out that the cygwin `less` is compiled with `terminfo`, so I also had to complie a new terminfo. Screen helps with that: http://aperiodic.net/screen/commands:dumptermcap